# Swiper thumb slider is not wokring

Tags: javascript, typescript, swiper.js

Trying to create a thumbnail gallery which will control a main gallery. my code is look like this:

```js
import Swiper, { Controller, Thumbs } from "swiper";

Swiper.use([Controller, Thumbs]);
...
...

const galleryThumbsEl = this.el.shadowRoot.querySelector(".thumbs-gallery") as HTMLElement;
this.galleryThumbs = new Swiper(galleryThumbsEl, {
  direction: "vertical",
  spaceBetween: 6,
  slidesPerView: 4,
  slideToClickedSlide: true,
  watchSlidesVisibility: true,
  watchSlidesProgress: true,
});

const galleryMainEl = this.el.shadowRoot.querySelector(".main-gallery") as HTMLElement;
this.mainGallery = new Swiper(galleryMainEl, {
  slidesPerView: 1,
  slideToClickedSlide: true,
  thumbs: {
    swiper: this.galleryThumbs,
  },
});

this.mainGallery.controller.control = this.galleryThumbs;
```

And view is look like this:

[image]

**How it's behaving:**
When I drag main slider to change slide it changes and thumb gallery slide changes too. But click on thumb gallery slide is not working.

So, if I click on thumb, it should change the slide of the main gallery, but it's not working like that.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: A snippet would be great

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy thanks for your reply. Sorry don't understand what type of snippet? I've already shared my code in the question.

Comment: A reproducible working example we can use to test. By clicking edit, then clicking on the `<>` you can create a snippet.